# Method that generates repeated code. How to simplify?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm learning Java and I will have to make a project for a university project.

```
    public double getCreditAmount() {
    return movementList.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getDate().before(tomorrow()))
            .filter(s -> s.type() == MovementType.CREDIT)
            .mapToDouble(s -> s.amount())
            .reduce(Double::sum)
            .orElse(0.0);
}

public double getDebitAmount(){
    return movementList.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getDate().before(tomorrow()))
            .filter(s -> s.type() == MovementType.DEBIT)
            .mapToDouble(s -> s.amount())
            .reduce(Double::sum)
            .orElse(0.0);
}

public double updateBalance(){
    return sumOfTotal = getCreditAmount()-getDebitAmount();
}
```

This is my code that taking an enum (DEBIT OR CREDIT), adds the present values ​​and the updateBalance method subtracts them from each other.
But I understand that this way produces repeated code that I could somehow avoid.
How could I avoid repeated code?
I know I should create a more general method which avoids repeating code of getCreditAmount () and getDebitAmount (). But how am I supposed to do it?

Comment: I'm quite suprise that you wrote such code, and no know about the parameter, or it's not your code ? Parameters in method is so much more basics than this code

Comment: @azro - He is learning.  (Actually, it is nice to see that some Unis are now *teaching* Java streams.)

Comment: @StephenC right. In this period we are learning programming through streams

Comment: @azro the written code is my pure fantasy and creation. I simply haven't thought about this type of solution, maybe because I'm a little careless or maybe just out of ignorance since I'm not very good at programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like other have said, you may pass the movement type as a parameter, this follows a key principle in coding is DRY (Do not repeat yourself).

Other things you need to do:

1. Give your method a generic name because it now supports two operations: CREDIT and Debit E.g. get, fetch, compute. I choose compute because we are doing some computations in that method.
2. I have concerns what you are doing in mapToDouble because it is an intermediate operation returning a DoubleStream consisting of the results of applying the given mapper function to the elements of this stream. So I am assuming that s.amount() is not returning a double so I am passing the amount (s.amount()) to the Double::parseDouble to parse the input to Double value

Here is how I would approach this problem

```
public double computeAmount(MovementType type) {
    return movementList.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getDate().before(tomorrow()))
            .filter(s -> s.type() == type)
            .mapToDouble(s -> Double::parseDouble(s.amount()))
            .reduce(Double::sum)
            .orElse(0.0);
}

public double updateBalance(){
    return computeAmount(MovementType.CREDIT) - computeAmount(MovementType.DEBIT); 
}
```

Comment: Except you are sure that s.amount() returns a string you can remove the Double::parseDouble with what you had before.  You may ask further questions using the comment or accepting an answer.

Comment: Thanks to the immediate response. s.amount() return a double value. I need to use Double::parseDouble or not?  Do you think I can simply use .map() or need to use .mapToDouble() anyway?

Comment: Yes please. You don't need mapToDouble in this case.

Comment: Note, you can make your compute/getAmount method provide if it should not be accessible outside the class. It is called Encapsulation. A key tenet of OOP

Comment: Thanks. I will take your advice into consideration.

Comment: Correction to the typo error: Note, you can make your compute/getAmount method PRIVATE ... It is private not provide

Answer (score 1):

As the only difference is the `MovementType` value, apss it as a parameter:

```
public double getAmount(MovementType type) {
    return movementList.stream().filter(s -> s.getDate().before(tomorrow()))
                       .filter(s -> s.type() == type).mapToDouble(s -> s.amount())
                       .reduce(Double::sum).orElse(0.0);
}
```

And use like this (no need of an intermediate `sumOfTotal`  variable)

```
public double updateBalance(){
    return getAmount(MovementType.CREDIT) - getAmount(MovementType.DEBIT); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response.
I had not thought of this solution to take the MovementType type parameter.
Thank you. Have a good day.

Comment: @acata8 You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just implement one method and pass the `MovementType` as a parameter:

```
public double getAmount(MovementType movementType) {
    return movementList.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getDate().before(tomorrow()))
            .filter(s -> s.type() == movementType)
            .mapToDouble(s -> s.amount())
            .reduce(Double::sum)
            .orElse(0.0);
}

public double updateBalance() {
    return getAmount(MovementType.CREDIT) - getAmount(MovementType.DEBIT);
}
```

A valid alternative would be to define an additional `getBalanceAmount()` method that does it all in one go. This prevents having to stream the list twice:

```
public double getBalanceAmount(){
    return movementList.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getDate().before(tomorrow()))
            .mapToDouble(s -> s.amount() * (s.type() == MovementType.DEBIT ? -1 : 1)
            .reduce(Double::sum)
            .orElse(0.0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to the immediate response. I believe I will opt for the solution with the two divided methods. Excellent intuition however.
Thank you. Have a good day